# How to repair the system after an accidental deletion of the kernels?

Tags: boot, kernel

*(newbie alert!)*. So basically, a window kept pop-in out saying that

> the volume "boot" has only 0 bytes disk space remaining

So I searched for a solution and I found one saying that I should delete the old kernels. I followed the steps and apparently I deleted all the kernels or the original kernels I'm not sure. After restarting my computer, the screen stuck in a black window. But when I force shut down, and start the computer again then I enter the boot menu F12, I choose the HDD I'll have something like this :

GNU GRUB version 2.02~Beta2-9ubuntu1.11+elementary10~ubuntu0.3.2.1

- elemnetary OS
- Advanced options for elementary OS
- Memory test (memtest 86+)
- Memory test (memtest 86+, serial console 115200)

So, I choose "Advanced options for elementary OS" then I have to choose between seven kernels, the first one doesn't work it.But, the rest do. The second one works perfectly fine. So, every-time I turn on my computer I have to follow all these steps. I think if I update the software It'll fix that. But, the "boot" still has only 0 bytes. Basically, I'm stuck between two problems.Is there a way to repair the system without loosing all my data?

Answer (score 1):

sudo update-grub

Should fix your booting issue and:

sudo apt-get autoremove

Should remove older kernels and packages that are no longer used and free up some disk space.
Future updates will replace whatever it was you deleted but if your still having issues then:

sudo apt-get --fix-broken install